# Why can't I mask a image to another image in xd?

Tags: website-design, layers, interface-design, mask, adobe-xd

I am using Adobe XD. And at a point I wanted to mask two images, but somehow I am not able to mask a image above another image.

> Note: When I tried masking it using an object I was able to do the same.

Then why when it comes to masking with two images adobe xd dose not allow??
Please refer the screenshot below for your understanding.

[image: Screenshot]

Please Help.
Thank You!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/155572/edit) and include a screenshot showing what you are trying to achieve or what has failed. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @BillyKerr I have updated the question, please answer if you can. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for that.  As far as I know, I don't think it's possible to mask a raster image with another raster image in XD. It needs to be an actual vector object, or text object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must need a vector shape/ object to create mask in XD.

In first example rectangle is what masking the fruit image.

But In second case there is no shape to mask the cat.

A picture itself is not a mask! You have to have a vector shape/ object  to mask an image, otherwise it simply won’t happen.

And If you think you will include/incorporate an image into already a masked object, XD doesn't work that way.

[image]

Comment: Noted with thanks!! @Never Look Back

Comment: You are Welcome :)